# How to use group_by() to display earliest date

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble called `master_table` that is 488 rows by 9 variables. The two relevant variables to the problem are `wrestler_name` and `reign_begin`. There are multiple repeats of certain `wrestler_name` values. I want to reduce the rows to only be one instance of each unique `wrestler_name` value, decided by the earliest `reign_begin` date value. Sample tibble is linked below:

[image]

So, in this slice of the tibble, the end goal would be to have just five rows instead of eleven, and the single Ric Flair row, for example, would have a reign_begin date of 9/17/1981, the earliest of the four Ric Flair `reign_begin` values.

I thought that `group_by` would make the most sense, but the more I think about it and try to use it, the more I think it might not be the right path. Here are some things I tried:

```
  group_by(wrestler_name) %>% 
  tibbletime::filter_time(reign_begin, 'start' ~ 'start') 
#Trying to get it to just filter the first date it finds for each wrestler_name group, but did not work

master_table_2 <- master_table %>% 
  group_by(wrestler_name) %>% 
  filter(reign_begin)  
#I know that this would not work, but its the place I'm basically stuck
```

edit: Per request, here is the `head(master_table)`, which contains slightly different data, but it still expresses the issue:

```
1      Ric Flair  NWA World Heavyweight Championship              40            8          69   1991-01-11 1991-03-21
2           Sting NWA World Heavyweight Championship              39            1         188   1990-07-07 1991-01-11
3      Ric Flair  NWA World Heavyweight Championship              38            7         426   1989-05-07 1990-07-07
4 Ricky Steamboat NWA World Heavyweight Championship              37            1          76   1989-02-20 1989-05-07
5      Ric Flair  NWA World Heavyweight Championship              36            6         452   1987-11-26 1989-02-20
6   Ronnie Garvin NWA World Heavyweight Championship              35            1          62   1987-09-25 1987-11-26
                   city_state country
1 East Rutherford, New Jersey     USA
2         Baltimore, Maryland     USA
3        Nashville, Tennessee     USA
4           Chicago, Illinois     USA
5           Chicago, Illinois     USA
6           Detroit, Michigan     USA
```

Comment: You have to filter for something: `filter(reign_begin == min(reign_begin))`, but I don't know if this works with dates.

Comment: Hey Martin, I appreciate both thoughts. I tried the ```filter(reign_begin == min(reign_begin))``` suggestion. It halved the numbers of rows, and worked somewhat. It reduced most of the ```wrestler_name``` instances down to two instances, but did not get the intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do this for databases involves a join:

```r
earliest <- master_table %>%
  group_by(wrestler_name) %>%
  summarise(reign_begin = min(reign_begin)

master_table_2 <- master_table %>%
  inner_join(earliest, by = c("wrestler_name", "reign_begin"))
```

No filter is required as an inner join only include overlaps.

The above approach is often required for database because of how they calculate summaries. But as @Martin_Gal suggests R can handle this a different way because it stores the data in memory.

```r
master_table_2 <- master_table %>%
  group_by(wrestler_name) %>%
  filter(reign_begin == min(reign_begin))
```

You may also find having the `lubridate` package installed assist for working with dates.

Comment: Hey Simon, Thanks for the post. I'm getting some weird returns. For 

```earliest <- master_table %>%
  group_by(wrestler_name) %>%
  summarise(reign_begin = min(reign_begin))
```
I'm getting a return of

```summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)```

Comment: For

```master_table_2 <- master_table %>%
  group_by(wrestler_name) %>%
  filter(reign_begin == min(reign_begin))
```

The tibble that returns still has duplicate wrestler_names.

Comment: Do you have any thought on alternative approaches or tweaks? Thanks!

Comment: The first message `ungrouping output` is not a concern. It just means that your output is no longer grouped following the summarise command. You can use `summarise(reign_begin = min(reign_begin), .groups = "drop")` to get rid of this warning (it is not an error, just a warning). It just means your'll have to call `group_by` again before your next summary - which is good practice anyway.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate wrestler names, there could be minor differences in the input text, e.g. `"Mr X"` is different from `"Mr X."` and `"Mr X "` (last one has a trailing space). To check this take a look at the output from `master_table %>% select(wrestler_name) %>% distinct()`. If you see duplicates here then there are slight differences in the input text.

Comment: Hey Simon, Appreciate you going the extra mile here. You are absolutely right. Apparently my dataset was not as clean as I thought I had made it, so I had some that were ```"Ric Flair"```, and others that were ```"Ric Flair "```. After struggling with it, I found that the following line trimmed the end off as intended:

 ```mutate_if(is.character, str_trim)
```

Thanks again for your time in helping me out on this one. I learned some cool stuff!

Comment: You are welcome. If your question is answered, I would encourage you to accept this answer (the tick beside the up/down vote arrows). This rewards me with some reputation and tells other users that the question has been answered.